# How to mock the module import of a class in pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to test a class which imports a function from some other module. I want to mock that function call. I cant figure out how though.

please_configure.py

```
from src.messages.create import create_please

class PleaseConfigure():
    def __init__():
        self._call = { "create_please": create_please }

     def handle_call(msg):
         self._call[msg["method"]](msg["args"])
```

create.py

```
def create_please(args):
    # does something not so important
```

test_please_configure.py

```
from src.consumers.please_configure import PleaseConfigure

@patch.object(PleaseConfigure, "_call")
def test_please_configure_success(mocked_call):
     cf = PleaseConfigure()
     # want to test cf.handle_call()
```

I have simplified the above classes to the point they obviously are no longer doing much, but this is the correct import hierarchy between the 3 files. How should I be mocking the function in the _call dictionary in instances of PleaseConfigure?

In test_please_configure_success I've tried variations on the following :

```
@patch.object(PleaseConfigure, "_call")
@patch.object(PleaseConfigure, "create_please")
@patch.object(PleaseConfigure, "src.messages.create")
@patch.object(PleaseConfigure, "src.messages.create.create")
```

I've also tried doing similar using context managers. It just doesn't seem to be working and is getting pretty frustrating. Appreciate any help mocking this function so I can test the PleaseConfigure class.

Comment: I find your question very interesting and are hoping for some good answers. Sadly, the way your question is formulated, it is possible that it will be closed as "too broad". Stackoverflow works best when you can present a concrete example with a specific question. The question "What is best practice here?" is often considered as mainly opinion-based. What is your current approach to deal with the task of accessing environment variables? Can you pin-point actual issues with it that you want to see addressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following worked.

```
@patch('src.consumers.please_configure.create_please')
    def test_handle_message(mocked_create):
        cf = PleaseConfigure()
```

The cf instance has the dict _call { "create_please": create_please } which is now an instance of MagicMock and has a reference mocked_create passed in as an argument.